# Testing SocketChannel NIO

Tags: java, sockets, scala, nio, channel

I just wrote some NIO-code and wonder how to stress-test my implementation regarding

- SocketChannel.write(ByteBuffer) not able to write the whole byte-buffer
- SocketChannel.read(ByteBuffer) reading the data in chunks into ByteBuffer

are there some simple linux-utilities like telnet to open a ServerSocket with some buffering-options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try original W. Richard Stevens' [sock](http://homepage.smc.edu/morgan_david/cs75/labs/stevens-sock.htm), it gives you ton of options.

Comment: Thanks, is there something on a level above TCP?